# How to authentication with Xero and salesforce without repeating authentication steps using apex?

Tags: authentication, salesforce, apex-code, xero-api

Could you please help how to authentication with Xero and Salesforce using apex without repeat steps of authentication process on Salesforce side?
As of now I used refresh token but it's expire after 60 days and I have to do authentication again. How can I get rid of this?
Please help.

I tried refresh token but it still expire after 60 days and I have to do authentication again. How can I remove this authentication steps again and again?

Answer (score 0):

Utilising the offline_access scope, you get a refresh and access token.

The access token lasts 30 minutes and the refresh token lasts for 60 days or until it used in a refresh call when you need a new access token.

When you make a refresh call, you get a new access and a new refresh token.

As long as you are refreshing regularly and storing the new refresh token, you shouldn't need to reauthenticate in Salesforce

Comment: Hi There @sallyhornet,
Thanks for your reply. I have a question, Do we have to call refresh token each and every time as we call our api for get or post then what about limit? or we have to create schedule class for generate refresh token once a day? I am confuse.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is up to you and depends on how often the API is used. Some developers add a refresh script before every call, others will schedule the refresh, others will add a script to check the access token is valid and then only refresh if the token expiry date and time is before the current time. Refreshes do not count towards the API call limits